# Extracting numbers after a specific word (stringr)

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, text-mining, stringr

I am trying to extract salary information from online job postings, from the job "description" column below:

Specifically, I would like to create a new column called "salary" based on the figures before the word "﷼" which refers to salary information per job posting.

```
description
<chr>
We are hiring

Project Manager

-Civil engineer Back ground

-language ( Arabic speak an read ) ( English speak and read)

-infrastructure experience

-consulting

- Location (Riyadh and Jeddah)

Contract length: 12 months

Job Types: Full-time, Contract

Salary: ﷼20,000.00 - ﷼30,000.00 per month

Experience:

* consulting: 6 years (Preferred)
* Project Management: 6 years (Preferred)

Location:

* Riyadh (Preferred)

Language:

* English (Preferred)
* Arabic (Preferred)

Work Remotely:

 * No

We need a marketing employee to: -

Work on increasing the company's sales and increase the number of social media
followers.

Design and publish advertisements.

To be a Saudi national.

He /she is fully aware of the methods of using social media in advertising.

Experience in design software like Photoshop and Illustrator is preferred.

Experience in marketing.

Application Deadline: 3/18/2021

Job Types: Full-time, Permanent

Salary: From ﷼4,000.00 per month

Education:

* Bachelor's (Preferred)

Location:

* Riyadh (Preferred)

Work Remotely:

* Yes

COVID-19 Precaution(s):

* Social distancing guidelines in place
```

I have tried the following using Stringr

```
str_extract(description, "(?i)(?<=﷼\\D)\\d+")
```

But I keep receiving this error message:

```
"restarting interrupted promise evaluationinternal error -3 in R_decompress1Error in str_extract(description, "(?i)(?<=<U+FDFC>\\D)\\d+")"
```

Comment: can you include `dput(head(your_data))`

Comment: The sophisticated way to do this is with "lookahead" and "lookbehind" elements in the regular expression (now that you know the term, you can search), *or* (more brute-force), first extract the element containing "[numeric + commas + dot]﷼ ", then delete "﷼ " from the end of the result (I don't see any instances in the example you show where the number to be extracted comes *after* ﷼? , but you can do the analogous operation